# Is there a mistake in the beginning of September's bassline?

Tags: bass-guitar

I love focusing on the basslines of the songs I like because I used to play the bass.
While listening to September by Earth, Wind & Fire, I noticed that around [0:15](https://youtu.be/Gs069dndIYk?t=15) the bass is a bit off.

My question is simple: as I am not an expert on bass, is it a mistake (which I doubt) or is it some special interval that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a bass player who has played this song dozens of times (probably an understatement) I learned the bass lines for the various sections but never actually transcribed the entire part. I was surprised by 2 things I never noticed.

1. The first 3 low A’s are an octave higher than the rest
2. The little “syncopation” figure at the end of bar 2 you mentioned

[image]

The reason I put syncopation in quotes is it doesn’t seem like he does that anywhere else in the song so it’s possible it was a slight mistake and very clever save on Verdine’s part, displacing the two high notes by a 16th. Remember this was way before the days of easy digital editing, this was all recorded to tape. Fixing a part was destructive and involved extreme punching in skill by the engineer and was only done when absolutely necessary. He didn’t play it on an older live version I saw on YouTube and later on the band started playing a tutti rhythmic figure in that spot. My take is it was unintentional but he pulled a rabbit out of his hat and made it work.

Answer (score 4):

I don't hear anything weird that can be suspicious of a mistake. The bass is playing (A - G - A ) over a A7 chord, which are the root and the minor seventh of the chord, no special interval, but rather typical. There is some slight syncopation around 0:15 where he delays the G a bit (so the G and the higher octave A land in up-beats), but that is also very controlled, precise and normal.

Comment: I just realised that I did not mean interval but time gap, sorry for the bad wording here. Thank you for the answer. So the thing I should look up is _syncopation_? This delay is on purpose ?

Comment: yeah you should look up that term, which of course will open a larger world. Pay attention to rhythmic variations bass players and drummers do on live recordings and you will start learning the type of things that usually is played on different music genres. On these kind of musicians and recordings you are safe to assume things are done on purpose.

Answer (score -1):

I hear this syncopation oddity every time I listen to this song.Seems like a  tape splice hiccup that they just had to live with, but I've never been able to confirm this suspicion.